# React Native iOS release build linking problem

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I recently upgraded my project from rn 0.57.x to 0.60.5. Now I am unable to successfully create a release build. It fails with `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`. It seems like the reason for the failure is that static libraries of the pods project won't be built when using a release scheme.

However, building with a debug scheme (or using a release scheme on my pre-upgrade rn 0.57 project) produces the missing .a files in the build output folders and everything works fine.

I tried several suggested fixes from other postings but I could not get past the errors. I have the same problem both locally and on my MS App Center CI. I have been digging through the internet and spending days fiddling around with XCode build settings without a solution.

I am using:

- CocoaPods: 1.7.5
- XCode: 10.3 10g8

Out of curiosity about my rn upgrade skills I created a fresh 0.60.5 project with rn cli init. To my surprise the fresh sample project didn't build either and fails with the same messages.
https://bitbucket.org/geekazoid_at/rn60test (Initial commit is 0.60.5, commit 30545e3 is 0.61.0-rc.0, both failing the same way.)

I strongly believe that if I can build rn60test, I will be able to fix my projects build problems too. Feel free to check it out and run `xcodebuild` against it or try building it in XCode (both fails the same way with a release scheme).

I still don't believe that this could be a bug, simply because the problem occurrs in such a fundamental task and it's impossible that it could go unnoticed. So I ended up here as Github suggested that "questions" should go on stackoverflow.

I don't understand why the release build suddenly produces different artifacts (missing static libraries) after the upgrade. Here is part of the builds output:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAwesomeProject-fofogldymcvznxdtbzasfqctwyio/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/OperatorApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/CocoaLumberjack'
... more ld -L warnings...
... more ld -L warnings...
... more ld -L warnings...
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAwesomeProject-fofogldymcvznxdtbzasfqctwyio/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/OperatorApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-splash-screen'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAwesomeProject-fofogldymcvznxdtbzasfqctwyio/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/OperatorApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/yoga'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Fode_modules'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Feact-native-background-fetchios'
ld: library not found for -lCocoaLumberjack
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAwesomeProject-fofogldymcvznxdtbzasfqctwyio/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/OperatorApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyAwesomeProject.build/Release-iphoneos/MyAwesomeProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyAwesomeProject normal armv7
    Ld /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAwesomeProject-fofogldymcvznxdtbzasfqctwyio/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/OperatorApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyAwesomeProject.build/Release-iphoneos/MyAwesomeProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyAwesomeProject normal arm64
```

Comment: are you using pods?
make sure you have properly link react-native-splash-screen lib.
try to remove DerivedData and run again

Comment: I'll try it out soon and get back to you, but I don't expect it to work, given the fact that the clean rn init project also fails. It has no 3rd party deps and it fails at finding DoubleConversion, rather then CocoaLumberjack in my real project (which seems to be an indirect dependency of one of the backgrounding libs).

Comment: And yes, using CocoaPods. Relinking (sure, I clean my derived data a lot) didn't make a difference and the problem persists. Debug spits out all required static libs of pods and their dependencies, release build does not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm updated my App in this month (**0.57 -> 0.60.5**), I'm used this link for it:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Roll back all the updates you made, and try it.

And after update, unistall your App and install again.

Comment: I couldn't get past the error. I suppose there is a problem with some of my pbxproj settings. I gave up on it for now and just upgraded to 0.59. Thank you anyway.